# How to plot diverging bar plots in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hi I am relatively new in R / `ggplot2` and I would like to ask for some advice on how to create a plot that looks like this:

[image]

Explanation: A diverging bar plot showing biological functions with genes that have increased expression (yellow) pointing towards the right, as well as genes with reduced expression (purple) pointing towards the left. The length of the bars represent the number of differentially expressed genes, and color intensity vary according to their p-values.

Note that the x-axis must be 'positive' in both directions. 
(In published literature on gene expression experimental studies, bars that point towards the left represent genes that have reduced expression, and right to show genes that have increased expression. The purpose of the graph is not to show the "magnitude" of change (which would give rise to positive and negative values). Instead, we are trying to plot the NUMBER of genes that have changes of expression, therefore cannot be negative)

I have tried `ggplot2` but fails completely to reproduce the graph that is shown. 
Here is the data which I am trying to plot: [Click here for link](https://uploadfiles.io/newbd)

```
> dput(sample)
structure(list(Name = structure(c(15L, 19L, 5L, 11L, 8L, 6L, 
16L, 13L, 17L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 14L, 18L, 7L, 12L, 10L, 9L, 4L, 20L
), .Label = c("Actin synthesis", "Adaptive immunity", "Antigen presentation", 
"Autophagy", "Cell cycle", "Cell division", "Cell polarity", 
"DNA repair", "Eye development", "Lipid metabolism", "Phosphorylation", 
"Protein metabolism", "Protein translation", "Proteolysis", "Replication", 
"Signaling", "Sumoylation", "Trafficking", "Transcription", "Translational initiation"
), class = "factor"), Trend_in_AE = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
), .Label = c("Down", "Up"), class = "factor"), Count = c(171L, 
201L, 38L, 63L, 63L, 47L, 22L, 33L, 20L, 16L, 16L, 7L, 10L, 4L, 
13L, 15L, 5L, 7L, 9L, 7L), PValue = c(1.38e-08, 1.22e-06, 1.79e-06, 
2.89e-06, 0.000122, 0.000123, 0.00036, 0.000682, 0.001030253, 
0.001623939, 7.76e-05, 0.000149, 0.000734, 0.001307039, 0.00292414, 
0.003347556, 0.00360096, 0.004006781, 0.007330264, 0.010083734
)), .Names = c("Name", "Trend_in_AE", "Count", "PValue"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```

Thank you very much for your help and suggestions, this is really help with my learning.

My own humble attempt was this:

```
table <- read.delim("file.txt", header = T, sep = "\t")
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(aes(x=Number, y=Names)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position="identity") + 
  xlab("number of genes") + 
  ylab("Name"))
```

Result was error message regarding the aes

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please do rather create a sample data frame or dput() your data instead of linking to a dataset.

Comment: ?? Also: Why must the x-axis be positive in both directions?? This doesn't make any sense to me. You are stating that the expression to the right is increased and to the left is decreased. In mathematical terms, this is positive and negative to me. Please elaborate

Comment: Also post the `ggplot2` code that you tried so others can help

Comment: I have updated the question to include the explanation

Comment: Please add the data as code.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure if the code is pasted in correctly but it's supposed to look like a table

Comment: question is too broad - there are several parts, including a) how to arrange the bars with axes labeled positive in both directions, b) how to arrange factor labels either side of center line, c) how to make a diverging colored scale centred at 1 and going down in each direction.  You need to try solving each of these issues individually, and post a targetted question for each issue you cannot solve.  You also need to show your own attempts.  SO is not a free code-writing service, and there is an expectation that people here have had a serious attempt themselves

Comment: I have indeed attempted and I will post the methods I have used later

Answer (score 2):

Although not exactly what you are looking for, but the following should get you started. @Genoa, as the expression goes, "there are no free lunches". So in this spirit, like @dww has rightly pointed out, show "some effort"!

```
# create dummy data
df <- data.frame(x = letters,y = runif(26))
# compute normalized occurence for letter
df$normalize_occurence <- round((df$y - mean(df$y))/sd(df$y), 2)  
# categorise the occurence
df$category<- ifelse(df$normalize_occurence >0, "high","low")
# check summary statistic
summary(df)
       x            y           normalize_occurence 
a      : 1   Min.   :0.00394   Min.   :-1.8000000  
b      : 1   1st Qu.:0.31010   1st Qu.:-0.6900000  
c      : 1   Median :0.47881   Median :-0.0800000  
d      : 1   Mean   :0.50126   Mean   : 0.0007692  
e      : 1   3rd Qu.:0.70286   3rd Qu.: 0.7325000  
f      : 1   Max.   :0.93091   Max.   : 1.5600000  
(Other):20                                         
category        
Length:26         
Class :character  
Mode  :character 

ggplot(df,aes(x = x,y = normalize_occurence)) + 
      geom_bar(aes(fill = category),stat = "identity") +
      labs(title= "Diverging Bars")+
      coord_flip()
```

[image: Diverging bars]

Comment: Hey! I am repeating your syntax, but somehow I cannot use my value (=1) as breakpoint. So I cannot get the bars divergent. Instead, they're oriented to the same point but changing color based on their value

Answer (score 1):

@ddw and @Ashish are right - there's a lot in this question. It's also not clear how ggplot "failed" in reproducing the figure, and that would help understand what you're struggling with.

The key to ggplot is that pretty much everything that you want to include in the plotting should be included in the data. Adding a few variables to your table to help with putting bars in the right direction will get you a long way toward what you want. Make the variables that are actually negative ("down" values) negative, and they'll plot that way:

```
r_sample$Count2 <- ifelse(r_sample$Trend_in_AE=="Down",r_sample$Count*-1,r_sample$Count)
r_sample$PValue2 <- ifelse(r_sample$Trend_in_AE=="Down",r_sample$PValue*-1,r_sample$PValue)
```

Then reorder your "Name" so that it plots according to the new PValue2 variable:

```
r_sample$Name <- factor(r_sample$Name, r_sample$Name[order(r_sample$PValue2)], ordered=T)
```

Lastly, you'll want to left-justify some labels and right-justify others, so make that a variable now:

```
r_sample$just <- ifelse(r_sample$Trend_in_AE=="Down",0,1)
```

Then some fairly minimal plot code gets you quite close to what you want:

```
ggplot(r_sample, aes(x=Name, y=Count2, fill=PValue2)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  scale_y_continuous("Number of Differently Regulated Genes", position="top", limits=c(-100,225), labels=c(100,0,100,200)) +
  scale_x_discrete("", labels=NULL) +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low="blue", mid="light grey", high="yellow", midpoint=0) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_minimal() +
  geom_text(aes(x=Name, y=0, label=Name), hjust=r_sample$just)
```

You can explore the [theme commands on the ggplot2 help page](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/theme.html) to figure out the rest of the formatting.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation and that was really helpful. Sorry for being quite new hear and not sure how to post.

Comment: Here I got an error message, but what does it mean?: > table$Name <- factor(table$Name, table$Name[order(table$PValue2)], ordered = T)
Error in `levels<-`(`*tmp*`, value = if (nl == nL) as.character(labels) else paste0(labels,  : 
  factor level [206] is duplicated

Comment: @Genoa: It means you are trying to duplicate levels in your factor (Name) which is not allowed. Assuming that you are starting with the dataset you provide in the question and then running the code I've provided as written (except replacing "r_sample" with "table"), I don't know how you can get that error. I'd check for objects with the same names in your workspace, or something like that. Also, if this answers your original question, be sure to indicate so by accepting the answer and/or upvoting the useful responses.

Comment: Great explanation! If one changes the code to be: `r_sample$just <- ifelse(r_sample$Trend_in_AE=="Up",0,1)` you see the text on the bars on the left are left-justified and those on the right are right-justified. What I really want is for the text to be lined up in the center and spill outside of the bars. For example, "Replication" would start at the left most part of the bar and extend right, while the last "n" of "Antigen presentation" would be at the middle.

Answer (score 1):

Just try this,

```
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)

set.seed(1)
data <- data.frame(
  x = paste("Gene", 1:30),
  y = rnorm(30, 0, 50)
)

p1 <- data |> 
  mutate(mnls.grp = ifelse(y < 0, 1, 2)) |> # Just to separate y > 0 vs y < 0
  ggplot(aes(y, fct_reorder(x, mnls.grp), fill = y)) + # Try ?fct_reorder()
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(x = ifelse(y < 0, 3, -3), label = x), hjust = ifelse(data$y < 0, 0, 1), size = 2.5) +
  geom_segment(x = -100, xend = 100, y = Inf, yend = Inf, lineend = "square") +
  scale_fill_gradient2(expression(italic("P") * "-values"), low = "purple4", mid = "lightgrey", high = "yellow") +
  scale_x_continuous(position = "top") +
  labs(x = "Number of Differently Regulated Genes", y = NULL) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-100, 100)) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 9) +
  theme(
    panel.grid = element_blank(),
    axis.text.y = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.x = element_line(),
    axis.ticks.length.x = unit(0.5, "line")
  )
# p1

p2 <- data |> 
  ggplot(aes(y, fct_reorder(x, y), fill = y)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(x = ifelse(y < 0, 3, -3), label = x), hjust = ifelse(data$y < 0, 0, 1), size = 2.5) +
  geom_segment(x = -100, xend = 100, y = Inf, yend = Inf, lineend = "square") +
  scale_fill_gradient2(expression(italic("P") * "-values"), low = "purple4", mid = "lightgrey", high = "yellow") +
  scale_x_continuous(position = "top") +
  labs(x = "Number of Differently Regulated Genes", y = NULL) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-100, 100)) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 9) +
  theme(
    panel.grid = element_blank(),
    axis.text.y = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.x = element_line(),
    axis.ticks.length.x = unit(0.5, "line")
  )
# p2

p3 <- p1 + p2 + plot_annotation(tag_levels = "a") & theme(plot.tag = element_text(face = "bold"))
# p3

ggsave(plot = p3, "diverging_bar_plot.png", width = 6, height = 4, dpi = 600)
```

[image: diverging_bar_plot]