# which "geom_" one need use to create plot shown below

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly

I need to make a plot as shown in figure2, I tried changing multiple "geom_" functions. Can I get help? I'm able to plot something like this

[image: PLOT 1 WITH POINT/DOT]

using :

```
my_data$Genus = factor(as.character(my_data$Genus), levels=names(x))

ggplot(my_data,
       aes(x=Genus, y=log2FoldChange, color=Phylum)) +
  geom_point(size=6) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = -90,
                                   hjust = 0,
                                   vjust=0.5))
```

but instead of "dots" I want the horizontal bars as shown in the second figure.

[image: PLOT_2_Horizontal bars]

Comment: `geom_bar()` + `coord_flip()`, 
see: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_bar.html

Comment: Search for `diverging bar plot`, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49290010/how-to-part-diverging-bar-plots-in-r).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to part diverging bar plots in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49290010/how-to-part-diverging-bar-plots-in-r)